# Using jq to extract values in JSON array with a particular key boolean == true?

Tags: json, jq

So I have a JSON blob as below:

```
[
  {
    'id': 'something',
    'isSparse': true
  },
  ...
]
```

How do I write a `jq` command that'll filter out this JSON blob and *print me the IDs of all entries in the array that have isSparse == true?*

I tried the following:

`cat <blob> | jq -c '.[] | select(.operational | contains("true"))'`

but get the following, because obviously `true` is a boolean and not a string:

`jq: error: boolean and string cannot have their containment checked`.

Answer (score 21):

If the task is to "print the IDs of all entries in the array that have isSparse == true", an appropriate jq filter would be:

```
.[] | select(.isSparse == true) | .id
```

If there is any possibility of duplicate .id values, then the following could be used to ensure only distinct values are emitted:

```
map( select(.isSparse == true) | .id ) | unique[]
```

As @JeffMercado pointed out, if .isSparse is strictly boolean, then select(.isSparse) would suffice.

Answer (score 11):

I add this answer as it may be helpful in future for a related scenario. - 
A specific example of this would be accessing a poorly written API which returns the same key/value pair differently depending on which endpoint or filters were used.  This is highly annoying when interfacing, and the value is a string sometimes and a boolean at other times (furthermore, sometimes even a number, or a number as a string :| )

---

Adding `| tostring` will compare the value as desired;

`cat <blob> | jq -c '.[] | select(.isSparse | tostring | contains("true"))'`

or for an exact match, slight variant:

`cat <blob> | jq -c '.[] | select((.isSparse | tostring) == "true")'`

Answer (score 6):

I assume you mean `isSparse`.  The `select` filter takes in something that evaluates to a boolean value. `isSparse` is already a boolean so you just need to select it.  `contains` is used for checking if something is in another container (a string, array, object, etc.).

```
$ jq -c '.[] | select(.isSparse)' <blob>
```